# How I can get my DB values inside the tag of my Jquery UI pligin?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
    $(function() {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Scheme"];
      $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
```

I don want the values inside the tags. i have a JS page i need to make a function for connecting my DB to the auto complete plugin. How can i do it suggestions Please.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not connect to a database using only JavaScript and you should never show your database values in JavaScript as everybody can read them.

You have to use a server side script to connect to your database, resolving the autocomplete values and responding them to the autocomplete plugin.

So in gerenal you don't use a local "source" with the suggestions, but a server side script and getting the values through ajax calls:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete('url_to_server_side_script');
```

**EDIT**: So i looks like it is a JSP page. After getting the values wihtin the function, you have to create an output (and use the "reponse" to send it to the client) with each value in a new line looking like this:

```
ActionScript
AppleScript
Scheme
```

You can even use HTML to markup the match of the query string (let's asume it was "Sc"):

```
Action<em>Sc</em>ript
Apple<em>Sc</em>ript
<em>Sc</em>heme
```

Comment: thanks---yes in server side scripting i created a connection to the table which i need to be displayed in the auto complete option. the function name for that is 
public Employee getEmployeeName(string name) throws ClassNotFoundException,
   SQLException {--- under this function i got my values now should i connect this in the place of url. Can u suggest me the way to complete it??